# How to remove specific css property from one CSS class in order to apply another class that puts another property on it?

Tags: html, jquery, css

so I have form and that form is styled like this:

```
#msform input, #msform textarea {
    padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;
    background-color: #ECEFF1;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Because I am doing validation of input elements, I want to apply following CSS property `border: 3px solid red;` with jQuery. The problem is that if I do this `$("#make").addClass("invalid");` it doesn't apply `border: 3px solid red;` but it rather stays same `border: 1px solid #ccc;` (which is already defined in style for form).

The problem is that I cannot just remove `border: 1px solid #ccc;` from form style and then apply my class `invalid`, because there are multiple inputs in my form and when I remove it, it looks ugly + all inputs would be with red border which I obviously don't want like that, I would like to have red borders only on those inputs that are empty.

What I've tried is being more specific in jQuery (with selectors) and removing property but it doesn't work, even after clicking on my next button I still have border like this `border: 1px solid #ccc;`. Here's my code:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
var make = $("#make").val();
var model = $("#model").val();
var godina = $("#godina").val();
var engine = $("#engine").val();
var termin = $("#termin").val();
var usluga = $("#usluga").val();

if(make == ""){
    $('#msform input #make').css("border","");
    $('#msform input #make').addClass("validation");
    $("#proizvodjac_validation").addClass("validation");
    $('#proizvodjac_validation').html('whatever');
}



else{
current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
        
        
//Add Class Active
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show();
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
step: function(now) {
// for making fielset appear animation
opacity = 1 - now;

current_fs.css({
'display': 'none',
'position': 'relative'
});
next_fs.css({'opacity': opacity});
},
duration: 500
});
setProgressBar(++current);
  }

});
```

Comment: can you provide your .invalid class in css

Comment: `.invalid` class just contains `border: 3px solid red;`  @CyrusKabir

Comment: so maybe it's for higher Specificity in `#msform input, #msform textarea` ruleset. Specificity in a single class ruleset it's less than id + tag selector so as you know in css any selector with higher Specificity says the last word (style)

Comment: `#msform input, #msform textarea` is applying, that's true. But as I previously wrote in question I want to remove border from that stylization on particular element, in this case `$('#msform input #make')` and want to apply another border (which is basically in class of `.invalid`). I don't know how can I be more specific than this, I am providing the id of form, element and ID of that element.

Comment: did you try $('#youridorclass').attr('class', 'new-class'); ??

Comment: it's not about jquery it's about css, your main styles on input have higher specificity so it's just take that one. so for change style on particular element you can just have higher specificity  (inline css, !important, ..)

Comment: @Crystal I did, but I am getting an error that my `#msform input, #msform textarea` is invalid selector

Comment: @CyrusKabir The problem is that this isn't inline css, and I can't apply `$("#make").css("border","1px solid red !important");` it will give same results as trying to remove particular property (which I tried)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a bit of thinking and researching of significance and learning about how and what class will be applied (basically specificity) I realized that moving class `.invalid` before `#msform input, #msform textarea` matters. So I don't know if this answer will help anyone else, but I solved it by following way:

1. Copied all properties for `#msform input, #msform textarea` to `.invalid` class, and replaced border with my `border:3px solid red !important` and moved `.invalid` class before `#msform input, #msform textarea` in CSS stylesheet.
2. After that I was able to do following in jQuery
   `$("#make").addClass("invalid");` and border of `3px solid red` successfully applied to my element.